# How to customize Appbar command image in metro apps?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, appbar

I have metro application in which i am trying to implement Appbar command control.
Am able to display the Appbar with some images but the problem is the image is moving when i highlight(hover). Some of my code is here

`.homebtn1 .win-commandimage{ background-image: url('/images/homeActive.png');

    width:140px;
    height:75px;
};`

```
.appbarExtraClass .win-commandicon
{
height:75px;
width:140px;
margin:0px 2px 2px 2px; 
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what change do i need to made for my above css in order to make images constant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :disabled :hover and :active pseudo selectors and apply them to your appBar. It's likely that the styles are what is making the buttons move around a little. This article shows some of the how to's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj839733.aspx

This blog post shows a lot of colorizing and customizing appbar buttons http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2012/07/17/colorizing-a-modern-win8-javascript-appbar-and-appbarcommands.aspx